# Is there any Java library for command line, env variables , property files parsing?

Tags: java

Is there any Java library for command line, env variables , property files parsing and possible from other sources as well? I want a library which can parse  from all the sources mentioned above with a certain order of precedence. I did a google search but I couldn't find much.

In Go there is this https://github.com/spf13/viper
Trying to find something similar or better in java

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at JSAP (the Java Simple Argument Parser).
It can be used for command line argument parsing. I am unaware whether it can do the rest or you'd have to build it yourself on top of it.
http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/

Answer (score 1):

command line : read parameter `String[] args` of main-method
environment : `System.getEnv()`
properties : see `java.util.Properies`

Comment: yeah but I am looking for a library so I can reuse and maintain